# How the content provider is updated when you download a new image?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a curious question.

I know that Android has several default Content providers and we have several URIs to access data from these Content providers.

One of them being **MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI**.

What I wanted to know is how this Content Provider for exposing saved image data is updated when you download a new Image?

Which app or process takes care of this?
How is the details of the image added to the content provider?

Comment: why do you want to know app or process name?

Comment: both. I want to know the internal workings when a new image is downloaded. How is the details of the image added to the SQLite database ?

Comment: by calling `ContentResolver#insert()` method

Comment: So the default image downloader app does that ? Or let us suppose I download an image in chrome, so in this case chrome does that. Right ?

Comment: most likely, but indirectly - by using `MediaScannerConnection` - the docs say: *"MediaScannerConnection provides a way for applications to pass a newly created or downloaded media file to the media scanner service. The media scanner service will read metadata from the file and add the file to the media content provider. The MediaScannerConnectionClient provides an interface for the media scanner service to return the Uri for a newly scanned file to the client of the MediaScannerConnection class."*

Comment: @pskink You did not even mention the MediaStore.

Comment: @greenapps what do you mean by that?

Comment: @pskink The MediaStore in MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. The media store has all the data/info and is the provider. The scanner just puts data in the media store.

Comment: @pskink  Repeat: You did not even mention the MediaStore in your whole explanation.